# How would I get the column names from a Model LINQ?

Tags: linq, reflection

I am looking to get a list of the column names returned from a Model. Anyone know how this would be done, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example Code:

```
var project = db.Projects.Single(p => p.ProjectID.Equals(Id));
```

This code would return the Projects object, how would I get a list of all the column names in this Model.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, I don't have working experience with LINQ.

This is purely based on looking at MSDN.

`DataContext` has a `Mapping` property, which returns an instance of [`MetaModel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metamodel.aspx). 
`MetaModel` has `GetMetaType`, which takes a `Type`. In your case it could be `typeof(Project)`. 
`GetMetaType` returns a `MetaType` which has the [`GetDataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metatype.getdatamember.aspx) method, which takes a [`MemberInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.aspx) parameter. You will have to use reflection on your `Projects` object to get the `MemberInfo` object. 
The [`MetaDataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metadatamember.aspx) instance returned by `GetDataMember` should have all the things, you need.

I hope I am somewhat in right direction (purely looking at MSDN & traversing)

Comment: Instead of `MetaType.GetDataMember(MemberInfo)`, you can use [`MetaType.PersistedDataMembers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metatype.persistentdatamembers.aspx) which returns a collection of [`MetaDataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metadatamember.aspx) objects which has the `Name`, `MappedName`, `IsPrimaryKey` properties etc that you need. Then you don't need Reflection. `PersistedDataMembers` returns only properties persisted, whereas `DataMembers` will give you all properties.

Answer (score 15):

This would be nice to have as an extension method:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
  public static ReadOnlyCollection<MetaDataMember> ColumnNames<TEntity> (this DataContext source)
  {
      return source.Mapping.MappingSource.GetModel (typeof (DataContext)).GetMetaType (typeof (TEntity)).DataMembers;
  }
}
```

example:

```
var columnNames = myDataContext.ColumnNames<Orders> ();
```

Comment: this is a much better solution than using reflection. :)

Comment: You can also use the [PersistentDataMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metatype.persistentdatamembers.aspx) property in place of DataMembers to get only those properties that are persisted, rather than all properties on the object.

Comment: Orders is The name of the table you want to column names for.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks guys, you got me started on the right track.  I found my solution with the following code.  I can then iterate through the DataMembers and pull out their individual properties such as name, type, etc.

```
var db = new GMPDataContext();
var columnNames = db.Mapping.MappingSource
                    .GetModel(typeof(GMPDataContext))
                    .GetMetaType(typeof(Project))
                    .DataMembers;
```

Comment: Awesome...I'll be using this.

Comment: I just translated to VB.NET and works. If anyone wants to use in VB: myData.Mapping.MappingSource().GetModel(GetType(NameOfYourDataContextObject)).GetMetaType(GetType(TableObjectFromDataContext).DataMembers

Answer (score 3):

Your Projects wrapper will have a set of properties each with a [Column] attribute. So just use reflection to enumerate the properties with that attribute.

Comment: I don't understand why so many solutions use reflection. Scott Gu's solution to converting an IQueryable to DataTable uses reflection to build a schema from a table entity decorated with the TableAttribute. I'd rather "SELECT TOP 0 (field1, field2,...) FROM myTable" and execute the datareader as datatable.

Answer (score 2):

Using Todd Smiths(+1) solution you get all properties (included entity sets, etc).
To filter out all non-column properties this will do the trick:

```
var columnNames = db.ColumnNames<Orders>().Where(n => n.Member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() != null).Select(n => n.Name);
```

Comment: nice addition! Just what I was looking for!

Comment: You can also use the [PersistentDataMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metatype.persistentdatamembers.aspx) property in place of DataMembers to get only those properties that are persisted, rather than all properties on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your columns should be mapped as properties on your Project model. I'm not sure if you can get the underlying database structure when using LINQ to SQL. The entire point of LINQ to SQL is to abstract the database away.

Answer (score 0):

Here an another way:

```
        public string[] GetColumnNames()
        {
            var propnames = GetPropertyNames(_context.Users);
            return propnames.ToArray();
        }

        static IEnumerable<string> GetPropertyNames<T>(IEnumerable<T> lst)
        {
            foreach (var pi in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                yield return pi.Name;
            }
        }
```