# LINQ table enumeration with column enumeration

Tags: c#, linq

How do you get a list of all the tables and use that list to enumerate the columns?
I've found posts that describe one or the other, but not both.

My net-result is I want to generate a static class which contains names of all the columns in each tables so I could, for example, do:

```
comboBoxFoo.DisplayMember = SomeNamespace.SomeTable.SomeDisplayColumnName;
comboBoxFoo.ValueMember = SomeNamespace.SomeTable.SomeIDColumnName;
comboBoxFoo.DataSource = dingo;
```

I'm currently using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/360990/how-would-i-get-the-column-names-from-a-model-linq/363746#363746) method which while it works, it means I have to manually create my tables in a list.

I have a seperate command line project which generates the SomeNameSpace.SomeTable class manually and I add the generated class file in to the project.

Ideally, if I could loop through via a foreach of tables and do something like this:

```
foreach(var table in someTableNumerationMethodForAGivenContext())
{
    var columnList = databaseContext.ColumnNames<someTable>();
    foreach(var columnData in columnList)
    {
        DoJazz(columnData.Name);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this other than manually have to do the databaseContext.ColumnNames() ?

Edit 1:
We're using LinqToSQL. Moving to ADO.NET also an option on the table, but at the moment we have no pressing need to.

Edit 2:
I know L2S does databinding but what I'm after is getting a list of column names as strings from a table. L2S doesn't offer this or it's not apparent on my side.
I'd like to do something like: SomeTable.SomeColumn.ToString() or something. SubSonic has this.

Final:
Thanks everyone. all are very good answers and lead me to the answer. You guys rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nazadus,

Is this what you are looking for?

LINQ to SQL Trick: Get all Table [and Column] Names:
http://blogs.msdn.com/jomo_fisher/archive/2007/07/30/linq-to-sql-trick-get-all-table-names.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is essentially an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Linq to SQL is an ORM that will create prototype c# classes for you that contain the information you are describing.  It has excellent support for the kind of data binding that you have illustrated.

Comment: We are using Linq to SQL however I have no idea how to reference the column names are strings. Any links to offer so I can read up? I feel like I'm missing something entirely obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.metadatamember_members.aspx).

```
DataContext.Mapping.GetTable(yourTable).RowType.DataMemebers()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this.

A) Use SMO to get all the tables / columns in a database. You need to reference:

Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo

Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc

Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo

Then, you can do something like this:

```
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(".");
        Server server = new Server(connection);
        Database db = server.Databases["Northwind"];
        foreach (Table table in db.Tables)
        {
            foreach (Column column in table.Columns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Table: {0}, Column: {1}",table.Name,column.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

B) Use reflection to reflect over your assembly with the dataclasses generated by Linq to Sql. Anything with a Table attribute is a table, and anything with a Column attribute is a column. Let me know if you need a sample...